# How to call inteface of intermediate class

Tags: class, interface, architecture

Currently in my application i have such a classes:

`Tag`

`Post` which implements `ITagAble/TagAbleInterface`

`Link` which implements `ITagAble/TagAbleInterface`

I want my service to be working on interfaces. And also i have intermediate classes to map my `post_tag` and `link_tag` from database:

`PostTag` which contains `post` object and `tag` object and maybe date of added tag

`LinkTag` which contains `link` object and `tag` object and maybe date of added tag

So how to call interface of `PostTag` and `LinkTag` ? It's only gonna have some (same)method to set proper `post` or `link` object and date.

Comment: You aren't real on what you want to call on the PostTag and LinkTag objects.  Can you post the interface definition?

Comment: something like: 

```setTagAbleId(TagAbleInterface $tagAble)```

which will set ```$this->post = $tagAble->getId()``` in PostTag and ```$this->link = $tagAble->getId()``` in LinkTag

the interface just would look like this

interface some Name

Comment: Interface would be something like:
```interface SomeName
    {
        public function setTagAbleId(TagAbleInterface);
    }```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have these intermediate classes. Those are a side effect of a relational database. You should not replicate the database structure in the class structure.

A Post and a Link should have a collection of Tags, Tags should have no relation to a ITagAble.